# Pass two arguments from command line in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to pass two arguments from command line. I know how to pass one argument using CommandLine.arguments .

```
val arg1 = CommandLine.arguments();
```

But how to pass two arguments and use it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John says, since `CommandLine.arguments : unit -> string list`, you can extract both the first and the second argument by regular pattern matching on this list. Assuming the two first arguments can be named *foo* and *bar*, and should both be interpreted as strings, and that any other number of arguments (0, 1, 3, ...) is an error, you could write:

```
fun main () =
    let val (foo, bar) = case CommandLine.arguments () of
                              [foo, bar] => (foo, bar)
                            | _ => raise Fail "Usage: tool <foo> <bar>"

    in ...
    end
```

And performing transformations on `foo` and `bar`, such as conversion to numbers, is not terribly difficult from here. But in case your command-line arguments are optional, or you do not wish for the order of them to matter, or you want to provide multiple ways of specifying them – e.g. `-h` being an alias for `--human-readable` while both work – you should consider using a utility library in SML/NJ called GetOpt.

It provides a framework for specifying how command-line arguments should be interpreted in a dynamic way. You can read the [SML/NJ GetOpt documentation](http://reallylongword.org/projects/sml/getopt/README), which provides a small example. It is a quite generic library and adds some complexity that is perhaps not warranted until you have quite many arguments and cannot be bothered to handle all legal combinations of them.

Comment: I didn't know about that `GetOpt` library -- thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `CommandLine.arguments` is

```
unit -> string list
```

It doesn't return a single string, it returns a list of strings. Any passed argument will be in the list. You just have to extract them.

If you are passing a single string which splits into multiple arguments with something other than a space as a delimiter you could use `String.tokens` on it. For example,

```
String.tokens (fn c => c = #"|") "abc|de|fgh";
```

Which yields `["abc","de","fgh"]`. You need to pass to `String.tokens` a Boolean-valued function which can tell when a character is a delimiter.

Comment: Suppose I passed "abcdefg" and want "abcd" and "efg" to be separated. how to do this?

Comment: How is your program supposed to tell where the one argument ends and the other begins? The standard approach is that command line arguments are space delimited. If you pass a single string as one big argument then of course you need to parse the string -- but you haven't given any relevant info about what your actual parsing problem would be.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
Just use

```
sml "file.sml" "arg1" "arg2"
```

where arg1 and arg2 are stored in a list and can be extracted in program using "tl" and "hd" function of list.